# gradle - make a step 100% optional

Tags: jenkins, gradle, clover

We use **clover** for code coverage testing but it interferes with stack traces and error information. I want to be able to use `cloverGenerateReport` when doing automated builds via **jenkins** but to skip this step *entirely* when doing local builds.

I've tried the various suggestions from searches for 'gradle optional dependencies' but I can't seem to get **clover** completely out of the way.

Suggestions?

Comment: How is the task cloverGenerateReport triggered? Does Jenkins call it from the command line (gradle cloverGenerateReport) or does your build.gradle specify it as a dependency of another task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method [onlyIf](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:onlyIf(groovy.lang.Closure)).

```
cloverGenerateReport.onlyIf {
    project.hasProperty('enableClover') ? Boolean.valueOf(project.getProperty('enableClover')) : false
}
```

On the command line you can enable it by providing the project property:

```
gradle cloverGenerateReport -PenableClover=true
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to check if the environment variable "JENKINS_HOME" exists. If it does, then set cloverGenerateReport as a dependency to another task.

In your build.gradle:

```
def env = System.getenv()
if(env.containsKey('JENKINS_HOME')){
    reportTask.dependsOn cloverGenerateReport
}
```